# Отправляет один и тот же data-id для всех option select методом POST

Tags: php, javascript, post

Ajax методом POST отправляет один и тот же `data-id` для всех выбранных `select`, которых 5, `data-id` беру из бд в цикле `foreach`.

PHP :

```
 <div class="row services" id = "which" style='display:none;'>
   <label >Какой вид услуг вас интересует</label>
     <div class="working" id = "working">
        <?php $services_categories = get_header_services_categories() ; ?>
        <?php foreach($services_categories as $services_category) { ?>
         <div class="tr">
           <select class="service_category" name="service_category">
              <?php $id_cat; $i = 0; 
                foreach ($services_categories as $services_category) { 
                  if($i == 0) $id_cat = $services_category['id'];?>
                    <option value = "<?=$services_category['name']?>"
                       data-id = "<?=$services_category['id']?>" ><?=$services_category['name'];?>
                    </option>
              <?php $i++; } ?>
           </select>

        <select data-id="services" class="services" name="services">
           <?php $services = get_services_list($id_cat); ?>
           <?php foreach ($services as $service) { ?>
              <option value = "<?=$service['name']?>"><?=$service['name']?></option>
           <?php } ?>
       </select>            
        <a href="#add-link" class="del-btn" id = "del-btn">X</a>
     </div>
    <?php } ?> 
    <a href="#" class="add-link" id="add-link">Указать еще услугу</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('.service_category').change(function(){

        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var id_category = $(".service_category option:selected").data('id');
        var select = parent.find(".services");
        select.empty("option");

        $.ajax({
                    url: "/services/get_services_list",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({ 
                             id : id_category, 
                          }),

                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                var json = $.parseJSON(data);

                                $.each(json, function(i, elem) {
                                    select.append("<option value="+elem.name+">"+elem.name+"</option>");
                                });

                                jcf.replaceAll();
                            },

                            error: function(data)
                            {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
        });
```